# React component does not re-render if there is only one state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, video.js, react-state-management

I have 2 components -> a) VideoJSPlayer and b) VideosPage.

As the name suggests, VideoJsPlayer has the video player part (using videojs) and VideosPage shows videos using VideoJsPlayer component.

The code for each of the components is:

a) VideoJsPlayer

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";

const VideoJsPlayer = props => {
  let player = null;
  let videoNode = null;

  // Effect for first render only.
  useEffect(() => {
    player = videojs(videoNode, props, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log("onPlayerReady");
    });
    return function cleanup() {
      if (player) {
        player.dispose();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref={node => (videoNode = node)} className="video-js"></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoJsPlayer;
```

b) VideosPage

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import VideoJsPlayer from "../../components/VideoJsPlayer";

const VideosPage = props => {
  const [videoJsOptions, setVideoJsOptions] = useState({});

  // Effect for first render only.
  useEffect(() => {
    let videoJsOptionsTest = {
      autoplay: false,
      controls: true,
      sources: [
        {
          src: "/my-video.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        }
      ]
    };

    console.log("test");

    setVideoJsOptions(videoJsOptionsTest);

    // Cleanup on unmount.
    return function cleanup() {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <VideoJsPlayer {...videoJsOptions} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default VideosPage;
```

When I check the URL which renders the VideosPage component, I don't see any video. I'm assuming the state (videoJsOptions) is not yet updated in VideosPage and hence I don't see the video. I can see the console log - "test" though.

When I change the code of VideosPage to:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import VideoJsPlayer from "../../components/VideoJsPlayer";

const VideosPage = props => {
  const [videoJsOptions, setVideoJsOptions] = useState({
    autoplay: false,
    controls: true,
    sources: [
      {
        src: "/my-video.mp4",
        type: "video/mp4"
      }
    ]
  });

  // Effect for first render only.
  useEffect(() => {
    /*
    let videoJsOptionsTest = {
      autoplay: false,
      controls: true,
      sources: [
        {
          src: "/my-video.mp4",
          type: "video/mp4"
        }
      ]
    };

    console.log("test");

    setVideoJsOptions(videoJsOptionsTest);
    */

    // Cleanup on unmount.
    return function cleanup() {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <VideoJsPlayer {...videoJsOptions} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default VideosPage;
```

Now when I check the URL which renders the VideosPage component, I see the video.

My assumption is - In the first case, the state update is queued and never happens. Because if it did happen, it should have re-rendered the component and I should have seen my video.

I have also tried updating useEffect in VideoJSPlayer to run every time props changes, but it didn't help.

Any insights on this?

Thank you for your time.

Here is a sandbox : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-galileo-v8hmb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: thats not how you use ref, read about useRef

Comment: @DennisVash : Can you please elaborate? A callback is passed to the ref, as also shown in the documentation here - https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html. 

If there was a problem with ref, I'm guessing it should not have worked in the second case as well. Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: There is a problem with ref, can you make a sandbox with this example? codesandbox.io

Comment: Here is a sandbox of what's working and what's not - https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-galileo-v8hmb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes:

1. You can't use `videoNode` like that because Video.js uses `Ref` and since you are using React hooks you need to use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react"

const VideoJsPlayer = props => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    //...
    videojs(
      videoRef.current,
      props,
      function onPlayerReady() {
        console.log("onPlayerReady")
      }
    )
   //...
  }, [])

 return (
   <video ref={videoRef} className="video-js" />
 )
}
```

2. You don't need to use `useEffect` again in your `VideosPage` component since its already been used inside your `VideoJsPlayer` component. Your initial options need to set directly in  the `state` or outside the function like so:

```js
const initialOptions = {
 // ...
}

const VideosPage = () => {
  return <VideoJsPlayer {...initialOptions} />
}
```

Here is a working [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/videojs-react-hooks-example-o8pt8) example based on your code.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

1. I agree with the need to use useRef in React Hooks. But I believe that's not needed if you pass a callback in ref which updates another variable. But, thanks for your recommendation, based on that I have updated the code.

2. The reason why this works is because you have initialOptions out of the component and that ensures that it is set. It works for the second case in my question as well, where the initialOptions is set inside useState.

But, it does not work if you use initialOptions as a state variable and set it inside useEffect when the component mounts

Comment: You don't actually need to reuse `useEffect` again because it has been used already  inside `VideoJsPlayer` component. Take a look at the codeSandbox example, we set the `initPlayer` inside `useEffect` and set the dependencies to `props, player` which means that `useEffect` will remount based on these value changes. `props` here refers to `initialOptions`

Comment: Here is a sandbox of what's working and what's not - https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-galileo-v8hmb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: There is no problem in VideoJsPlayer component. My question is - If the state of VideosPage.js updates through useEffect, why is the video not being shown?

Comment: because can't use `useEffect` twice for the same purpose :) you'll need then to set the initial values instead of  `props` rather than passing it.